# Financial Reports On Form’s Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listview

I have to design a financial report using winforms.  I have choosen the ListView control for displaying financial Data like Profit & Loss Account, Balance Sheet, etc. But I'm having issues due to the limited features of Listview grouping.

I cannot just display a static report to the user, I have to create a form that acts like a report.  That means I need to create groupings, and subgroups, and apply totals to these.  This isn't possible (as far as I can tell) with the ListView.

I can actually create my report using Crystal Reports, and it looks exactly how I want, but then the user cannot edit the data.  That's why I'm trying to reproduce the report in a form.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look into the Data Grid which is designed for this sort of thing. The list view is designed for selecting items from a list, not complicated groupings and data editing.

Comment: Sorry but Data Grid is not available at vs-2005 for winapplication

Comment: sorry but I didn't get you what you mean?.

Comment: I'm saying there is definitely a winforms grid control available that ships with VS2005 (.NET 2.0).

Comment: It's under the 'Data' category, not in the 'Common Controls'

Comment: I think you are missing here and the point is Data grid and datagridview and as per your suggestion Under Data catagory there are Datagridview control not datagrid

Comment: @DavidMasters let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2694/discussion-between-mahesh-and-david-masters)

Comment: Datagridview is not really perfect for prepare a financial report as there are no groups option or feature are available.